How to cast my custom shared pointer in C++
I am creating a custom shared pointer in C++ to learn how these things work.
My implementation is not general purpose, I only want it to be used with a class Foo or an any of its subclasses.
This is what my classes look like:
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, Foo> || std::is_base_of_v<Foo, T>>>
class ReferenceCounter final
{
private:
    T* m_Value;
    unsigned int m_Counter;
};


template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, Foo> || std::is_base_of_v<Foo, T>>>
class SharedPtr final
{
private:
    ReferenceCounter<T>* m_ReferenceCounter;
};

I have also implemented all the constructors, copy constructors, assignment operators, etc. I didn't show them here because it is a lot of code and I don't think it is relevant to the question.
Now I want to add two functionalities:

I want to be able to implicitly convert a shared pointer from a subclass to a base class like this: SharedPtr<Foo> f = MakeShared<FooDerived>();
I want to be able to cast from a base class to a derived class, returning nullptr if the conversion is not possible: SharedPtr<Foo> f = ...; SharedPtr<FooDerived> fd = TryCast<FooDerived>(f);

How can this be implemented?

you say it should work only with Foo and its derived classes, but in the code there is a template argument T. Only Foo is considerably simpler than general T.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I've added a template restriction to only allow T to be replaced by Foo or one of its derived classes

You will have issues with dangling reference counters. Note that aggregation is an option, you can still use an std::shared_ptr as member variable. And then provide constructors etc... that resrict to Foo (no templates needed)

You need T* to be directly in SharedPtr, not next to the ref counter. Because when multiple inheritance is involved, after a pointer cast you can have a pointer with the same ref counter pointer, but a different object pointer.

You want a converting constructor, like in (9) ?

you need not add Edit1:... to the question. If someone wants to see the edit history they can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78371679/revisions (click on edited 42 mins ago)

Aside: std::is_base_of_v<Foo, Foo> is true, you don't need the std::is_same_v

typo: std::enable_if -> std::enable_if_t. The class exists always, only the member alias is a substitution failure.

This is not possible with the given design as stated in the comments. The SharedPtr<Foo> would have to store a pointer to the ReferenceCounter<FooDerived> provided by MakeShared<FooDerived>, which is not possible. The reference counting mechanics should not be templated to make this work.
class ReferenceCounter {
    ...
    unsigned m_Count;
};

template<class T, ...>
class SharedPtr {
    ...
    T* m_Value;
    ReferenceCounter* m_Ref;
};

Now, you have to create a converting constructor and do the necessary reference adjustments.
// Within the SharedPtr class

template<class Other, /* Only if T is a base of Other */>
SharedPtr(const SharedPtr<Other>& ptr) :
    m_Value(ptr.m_Value),
    m_Ref(ptr.m_Ref)
{
    // Increment the reference count, remember to check if ptr holds a non-null value/ref.
    ++m_Ref.m_Count;
}

// Also remember to friend the other class instantiations of SharedPtr
template<class Other>
friend class SharedPtr;

To cast base to derived, you will have to try something with dynamic_cast.
template<class To, class From, /* Only if Foo is a base of To and From */>
auto TryCast(const SharedPtr<From>& ptr)
{
    auto* value = /* Retreive m_Value from ptr */
    auto* ref = /* Retreive m_Ref from ptr */

    auto* new_value = dynamic_cast<To*>(value);
    if (!new_value)
        return SharedPtr<To>(nullptr);

    return /* SharedPtr<To> with m_Value = new_value and m_Ref = ref */
    // Remember to adjust the refcount
}


I would take this approach :
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Foo and Bar structs 

struct Foo
{
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
    virtual void DoSomething() const
    {
        std::cout << "Foo\n";
    }
};

struct Derived : 
    public Foo
{
    void DoSomething() const override
    {
        std::cout << "Derived\n";
    }
};

struct Bar
{
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// your own special shared pointer type
// Note, no inheritance here. But still reuse of std::shared_ptr

class shared_foo_ptr_t final
{
public:
    // make sure all the move and copy constructors are defined
    // since there is a custom (private) constructor
    ~shared_foo_ptr_t() = default;
    shared_foo_ptr_t(const shared_foo_ptr_t&) = default;
    shared_foo_ptr_t& operator=(shared_foo_ptr_t& ) = default;
    shared_foo_ptr_t(shared_foo_ptr_t&&) = default;
    shared_foo_ptr_t& operator=(shared_foo_ptr_t&&) = default;

    // here is your template function
    // with extra checks on Foo being a base
    template<typename type_t>
    static auto create() -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Foo,type_t>, shared_foo_ptr_t>
    {
        shared_foo_ptr_t shared_foo_ptr{ std::make_shared<type_t>() };
        return shared_foo_ptr;
    }

    // explicit! casting operator
    explicit operator std::shared_ptr<Foo>() const noexcept
    {
        return m_foo_ptr;
    }

    auto& operator->()
    {
        return m_foo_ptr;
    }

    const auto& operator->() const
    {
        return m_foo_ptr;
    }

    auto* get() 
    {
        return m_foo_ptr.get();
    }

private:
    explicit shared_foo_ptr_t(std::shared_ptr<Foo>&& foo) :
        m_foo_ptr(foo)
    {
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Foo> m_foo_ptr;
};

// helper function that looks like std::make_shared
template<typename type_t>
auto make_shared_foo_ptr() -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Foo,type_t>, shared_foo_ptr_t>
{
    return shared_foo_ptr_t::create<type_t>();
}


// show function using shared_foo_ptr_t
void fn(const shared_foo_ptr_t& shared_foo_ptr)
{
    shared_foo_ptr->DoSomething();
}

int main()
{
    auto foo_ptr = make_shared_foo_ptr<Derived>();
    fn(foo_ptr);

    //auto bar_ptr = make_shared_foo_ptr<Bar>(); // does not compile as it should

    // allow casting to a normal shared_ptr
    auto shared_ptr = static_cast<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>(foo_ptr);

    // then you have all the other shared_ptr facilities too
    auto derived_ptr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(shared_ptr);
    if ( derived_ptr != nullptr)
    {
        derived_ptr->DoSomething();
    }

}

